# How to fix Elasticsearch "Invalid index and/or indexing error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I had to format my computer, when setting up my local environment again  with Elasticsearch, I got this error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"model","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"model"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"model","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"model"},"status":404}

app/service_wrappers/elastic_search_client.rb:20:in `search'
app/queries/filter_query.rb:19:in `filter'
app/services/filter_services/apply_filters.rb:52:in `filter'
app/controllers/filters_controller.rb:70:in `apply_search'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:508:in `block in render_json_on_logged_in_exception'
lib/concerns/traceable.rb:14:in `trace'
lib/concerns/traceable.rb:40:in `trace_callback'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:506:in `render_json_on_logged_in_exception'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:209:in `block in catch_db_exceptions'
lib/concerns/traceable.rb:14:in `trace'
lib/concerns/traceable.rb:40:in `trace_callback'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:205:in `catch_db_exceptions'
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages, along with "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)"

Comment: Did you really need to downvote the question @theTinMan ?

Comment: Yes. Please read the reasons for downvoting (hover over the down arrow). Then carefully read the links I gave above. We're happy to work with you to improve the quality of your question, which is why I posted those links, but we expect effort to be put into the questions. SO isn't a message board, forum or "give me code" or magic answers site. We need you to put in a very sincere effort to tell us what is necessary to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to run the following

```
bundle exec rake elasticsearch:reload
```

In some cases you may need to run it this way

```
bundle exec rake elasticsearch:reload[instance]
```